# How should I use Twitter API in java?

Tags: twitter

I want to develop a web application that uses the Twitter API.

Where can i find examples

thanks for replay. I have downloaded an app from this site - github.com/yusuke/sign-in-with-twitter I have deployed and its running, but its giving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userId' not found on type twitter4j.Twitter this exception after giving log in credentials in twitter log in site. thanks in advance.

i am not able to resolve this issue. can anybody help on this

Comment: Just go through the API and example: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: please share the code where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/ seems to have no further support. I thoroughly recommend: http://twitter4j.org!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best java twitter library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851767/best-java-twitter-library)

Answer (score 4):

[Search for 'twitter api java examples' in Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter+api+java+examples) and you'll find plenty of examples.

See http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=89 for an example using Twitter4J.

As a connection library, you could use

- *Twitter4J* on http://twitter4j.org/
- *java-twitter* on http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/
- *JTwitter* on http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java Twitter - a pure Java interface for the Twitter API.

http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/

Documentation and examples are on that page too :)